# 403 (Forbidden) when using Ocelot with docker-compose and asp.net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, microservices, ocelot

I am trying to make use of Ocelot to redirect a request from a Web application using HttpClient to an Asp.Net Core WebAPI running in Docker.
Ocelot is also running in a container.
Both the containers (ProductManagementAPI and Ocelot) are created using docker-compose.

Below is my ocelot.json file:

```
"ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/product/product",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "productmanagementapi",
          "Port": "8100"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/product/product",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Options" ],
      "Priority": 1
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
  }
```

After running "docker-compose up" command when I directly browse: http://localhost:8100/api/product/product, I get the desired response.

But when I make a request from Webapp running locally to get the response from the API running in the container via the Ocelot Api gateway (also running in the container), I get the below error:

*ocelotapigateway_1       |       requestId: 0HLTAOJJEL03J:00000001, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: 403 (Forbidden) status code, request uri: http://productmanagementapi:8100/api/product/product*

Even if I replace the Downstream host in the ocelot.json file to "localhost" I get an error.

I have not enabled authorization in any of the above applications.

When I directly call the WebAPI running in docker using HttpClient from the WebApplication, it works. But when placing Ocelot gateway in between, it stops working.

Comment: Having the exact same problem :(

Comment: I found the problem, it was a proxy issue. Add the host IP in the no_proxy list. Though, still I can't use the service name from docker compose, but it works with host IP and port.